# Workflow column not available when provisioning view against list

Tags: 2010

Recently i created a web template and as part of the provisioning process i create various pages and assign a workflow to a list. I have a listviewwebpart that points to the list that i have attached the workflow to. I want to show the workflow column in this view but the workflow column is not added to the list until a workflow has been initiated.

Is there a way that you can attach a column to the list and then update the workflow to use that column so that its available to add to my view when it is provisioned.

Im totally stumped with this so any ideas are welcome